# expandable item to elevate above soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a scrollview, inside I have a couple of layouts ,and beneath them another scrollview that has Expandable items(simply extends of LinearLayouts that were customized).

When I open bottommost item, edittext is then shown and keyboard pops up. However I cannot see the edittext, as it is hidden behind the keyboard.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout...> 

        <RelativeLayout...>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/second_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <com.package.ExpandableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </com.package.ExpandableLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The LinearLayout and the RelativeLayout above the expandable items don't let the items to elevate up further. it only gets the the top of the FrameLayout and then stops , which is not enough since the keyboard at that level still hides the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use **android:windowSoftInputMode** to achieve this.Add this to your manifest.

```
            <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Comment: I have it set to adjustPan already, unfortunately it doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

May be....
try to add input mode in manifest in that activity, set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```